# Should i return a value for a Future<void> Function?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future, void

In Dart, there are 2 options for functions that run asychronously, but whose return values are not supposed to be used.

```
Future<Null>
Future<void>
```

Since Dart 2.0, it is often recommended to use void instead of Null in most cases (due to the warning that void types shouldn't be used).

For these, a return type should not be required, but one could return all types. But what is the best practice here, should i still return something, should i end the function with a empty return (1), return null or something else (2) or should i just end the function (3)? Did i maybe miss any essential differences between the 3 options, supposing the return value doesnt get used (f.e. await exampleFunction() should in all cases wait till the function completes)? Is it essentially just code style?

1)

```
Future<void> exampleFunction() async{
  ...
  return;
}
```

2)

```
Future<void> exampleFunction() async{
  ...
  return null;
}
```

3)

```
Future<void> exampleFunction() async{
  ...     
}
```

Comment: What would you do for a synchronous function that returned `void`?  For an `async` function that returns `Future<void>`, do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an *async* method returns `Future<void>` the best practice is to avoid the empty return at its end. However you can still use `return` to exit the method under certain conditions:

```
Future<void> exampleFunction() async{
  if (skip) return;
  await doSomething();     
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, was also my first intuition, to basically handle it like a sync void function, usually no return at the end, but if you want to return sooner, use the "return;". Since the 3 ppl that answered/commented seem to agree and your example highligts the use of the return best, i accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Future type just indicate the function will be called async.

Comment: "But what is the best practice here"  Use async/await, this way the code seems to be sync.
"should i still return something" I've never seen this situation before.

"Did i maybe miss any essential differences between the 3 options, supposing the return value doesnt get used (f.e. await exampleFunction() should in all cases wait till the function completes)? Is it essentially just code style? "

Its not just coding style. Returning void means the caller doesn't expect to be modified by the function. When you return null the caller gets nullified.